# Potential memory issues with navigating between pages in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

In a Nativescript 2.0 app, I can use the back button, combined with frameModule.topmost() to navigate to previous page. My question is, when someone uses my app and navigates all over the app, does it keep a history of all pages in a memory stack, and at some point, run out of memory? Does it affect performance? Is it a good idea to call clearHistory occasionally, if needed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it keeps a history of all pages in your "back stack". No this will not affect performance. It's a simple list, like "Page X, Page Y, Page Z".

However, if you have a big history stack your user experience will probably suffer as it will make it harder for your user to go back to, let's say the "main page", as the user have to navigate back and then back and then back and then...

Comment: Thank you. I've noticed, however, that as you go back to previous pages, it renders quickly - very, very quickly. I would imagine more than just a simple list is stored, and there might be some more data stored in memory. Do you know if that's the case?